# Is my PHP salt safe?

Tags: php, algorithm, encryption, coding-style

I'm wondering is my PHP salt safe also for open source? I've trying to search more information but I wasn't able to find what I needed to know.

my code:

```
<?php
class salter {

// this will create 3 ciphiers in order to make hashes clearly unreadable! (I hope...)
public function simpleSalt($password) {
    $salttypes = array (
            "92jX324BO(091jäZ",
            "ðáßk2a-jN9úá¡’A5R",
            "çíó‘’j(#)hAdH28sZV" 
    );
    $salt1 = $salttypes[0];
    $salt2 = $salttypes[1];
    $salt3 = $salttypes[2];

    $pepper = crypt($salt1);
    $moarpepper = crypt(salt2);
    $salt = crypt(salt3);

    return md5(bin64_encrypt($pepper + $moarpepper + sha1($password) + $salt));
}
}

?>
```

I'm planning to use a special charset for this table, but my question is could this make it harder to crack hashes or make it easier? since I'm also planning to make it open source I'm afraid it could be a measure of mistakes.

p.s I'm very new to salting

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is a code review request. This is better suited to http://codereview.stackexchange.com


Comment: salt should be random, and unique for each password. double hashing is also a bad idea, md5 is a bad idea

Comment: Stay away from `md5` (It's passé) – "Pepper" always adds (good) flavor, to anything ;-)

Comment: md5 is not secure.  Why not just use `password_hash` (http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.password-hash.php)?

Comment: Generate a new salt randomly every time a password is set and store it alongside the password. Don't use something deterministic to generate the salt (eg don't hash the current time).

Comment: Use the bcrypt library

Comment: Here. Take a read through this. http://codingkilledthecat.wordpress.com/2012/09/04/some-best-practices-for-web-app-authentication/

Comment: The most important question: Why exactly are you reinventing the wheel again? There's proven (and way better) implementations for password hashing widely available.